# If div class exists against a specific div ID jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following code:

```
if (jquery('#div1.class1').length) {
```

With 'div' being the name of the Div ID and 'class' being the name of the class id e.g.

```
<div id="div1" class="class1"></div>
```

However the code doesn't work. How do I specify that a specific class exists for a specific div (I have multiple div's with the same class)?

Thank you

Comment: Assuming `jquery` is a reference to `jQuery`, and you're running the code after the DOM has loaded then the code will work. As such, I suspect this is not the case. Check the console for errors

Comment: Also note that the `.class1` in the selector is redundant, as `id` selectors need to be unique in the DOM. If you have it repeated then that's another problem which needs to be fixed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I suspect `$("#div.class1").length` is used for `$("#div").hasClass("class1")` - ie won't find it if doesn't have the class

Comment: @freedomn-m The code looks fine and this will work `if (jQuery('#div1.class1').length) {}` the OP has some console errors. 100% - agree with RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes, the code should be fine as per first comment - I was referring to the use of `#div1.class1` which Rory mentioned was **redundant**.  To test if div1 has class1 you can't just do `$("#div1").length` which is implied by saying `.class1` is redundant - so `.class1` is not redundant.

Comment: @freedomn-m make sense. I guess by redundant he meant that `id` selector needs has to be unique to do `.length` - Rory is just adding extra info for OP to consider that too.

Comment: @freedomn-m make sense meant by that i understood what you said in the second last comments of yours :) Thanks

Comment: Would be better if OPs question was worded better as it contradicts itself.  I'm reading the question as "*How to find if class exists against a div*" and *"How do I check that a specific class exists"* - this is backed up by the code that does `if (.. .length)` which wouldn't be needed if you're trying to *find* a div by id and class.   I'm loath to edit the question now as it looks like others are reading it differently.

Comment: @Revokez please clarify: are you **trying to find** the div1 that has class1 (where there might be *another* div1 without class1)?  Or are you **trying to check if** div has (or does not have) class1 (where there is only 1 div1 and you want to know if it has class1 or not)?

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for your comments appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

No sense: if (jquery('#div1.class1').length) {
You can have just one unique element with ID div1 = #div1
in this case `<div id="div1" class="class1"></div>`